# Segmentation fault on method call

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I realize the debugger would help but Im a little lacking on knowledge of using it at the moment. But I promise I will begin learning it asap! So if anyone also knows some good reading on how I can learn to use gdb via prompt. Id greately appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Imo don't bother with gdb on the cli, it's more complicated to get what you want and less clear by default. Just use eclipse and its GUI - with that the learning curve for debugging is basically nil.

Comment: Yeah thats what I would prefer. But as a new programmer I feel it would be more beneficial to learn first before I take the easy route?

Comment: Post a sample vector file please ("Prj3 Config.txt")

Comment: Well there's really no reason that you have to know what the CLI commands are to print variables or see the code that you're currently stepping through, or how to step through it. The important things (difference between step, next, return,..) are all high level constructs that you can easily understand from the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's one big mess of code. I don't have a clue what it's for but there's one problem I can see

In your `Node` class you have an array of four `Node` pointers called `attachedNode`. At no time in your code do you make those pointers point at anything. But you dereference those pointers in your `attachNewNode` method. That's a seg fault right there.

I have no idea how to advise you to fix that problem (or any other problems you might have, I think there are a few) because I don't have much idea what the code is supposed to be doing.

However one piece of advice. This code is too big and complex. Get a smaller piece of it working first, and gradually build up to the whole program. The slow and steady approach will get you there faster in the end.

Comment: Well thats what Ive been doing. I test it as I go. As of now this is my only problem.

Comment: OK, that's good to hear. The code could be a little more polished however. For instance the way you read the same file literally hundreds of times is not good. Since the Node part is clearly the most complex part, perhaps you could try working on that in *isolation*, it will be easier to debug like that. Then when you have it working on it's own, you can incorporate it back into the main program.

Comment: I honestly think your code is OK as-is.  For now, the benefits of having "everything in one file" probably outweighs the added complexity of juggling multiple .cpp and multiple .h files.  For now, just resolve the current problem: 1) pick a debugger, 2) set breakpoints in "main()" and each constructor, 3) debug the crash.  I strongly believe something's not getting initialized.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4, Yes the `attachedNode` pointers in `Node`. Maybe they shouldn't be pointers at all? Hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks paulsm4. Im not surprised its not great.Basically my teacher says heres your project on a new subject, go do it. So Ive kinda been learning as I go. But If I were to redo it now that I understand nodes and pointers more clearly. It wouldn't be so crazy.

Comment: In the breakpoint you set in the debugger, you have the opportunity to see if they actually point to anything :)  For example, where do you initialize any of the members of array "Node * attachedNode[4]"?

Comment: In formArray(). It runs through each Node object in the array and either sets it to null(0) if the line and column is * or if the line and column is not * but a name of the node. Then it finds that node using its string name and sets the attacheNode's to the location of the other node. Does that make sense?

Comment: Im trying to set the breakpoint on main() but, break main() or break 199 are not working? Setting break Node::Node() works fine though?

Comment: @TheNodeCommode That's not what the code you've written does. At no point do you set the attachedNode to anything. Which function is it that you think sets the attachedNode? At some point in your code I would expect to see `attachedNode[i] = something;`, I'm not seeing that.

Comment: formArray() in my switch function. list[i] is a pointer to the array of nodes. Im going through each object and calling attachNewNode(memory location, 0-4) or setting it to null with attachNewNode(0)? attachNewNode() sets attachedNode[0-3] to "something".

Comment: OK but that's where the problem is. Inside `attachNewNode` you have this code `*attachedNode[direction]`. You are *using* the value of `attachedNode[direction]` but at no point in your code do you give `attachedNode[direction]` a value. So you cannot use it without crashing your program. You must give it a value before you use it.

Comment: Ah, Mabye thats my mistake then. Im just trying to set the attachedNodes to point to other nodes. They are edges that point in four "directions" to either other node objects or point to nothing(null). I think my attachNewNode() implementation may be wrong?

Comment: OK, I figured it was something like that, the problem is that the code you've written is not doing anything like that. As I said, if you want to give those pointers some values you should have `attachedNode[i] = something;` somewhere in your code. I'm sorry I can't give more specific advice, as I said I'm not really following the code very well.

Comment: Maybe your code should say `void Node::attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction) { attachedNode[direction] = newNode; }`. Just a guess.

Comment: Yes, thats what I was supposed to be doing. I mistaked that newNode was already a pointer and dereferenced them like you said before. But im still getting a seg fault = \

Comment: OK, more than one bug then. Just keep hammering away,

Comment: Thanks John for helping I really appreciate it. Other than the bug I have to find, now that ive changed that method. Does my formArray() seem to make sense? Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: @TheNodeCommode `attachladderChute` seems to have a similar problem. Assuming you are trying to assign the pointer it should be `void Node::attachLadderChute(Node *newNode) { ladderOrChuteNode = newNode; }`

Comment: As for going in the right direction, one problem is that you are repeatedly reading that file, literally hundreds of times. You should rearrange your code so that it is only read once (into some kind of vector) and from then on you query the vector not the file.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using GCC, I heartily recommend using GDB.

I love Eclipse ... but I usually find the command line faster and more useful.  IMHO...

ANYWAY:

1) compile with "-g" to allow debugging,

2) run your program inside of gdb,

3) note the line# it crashes on

4) Look *backwards* to see if there's something about that line you didn't allocate, you already deallocated or, most likely, you overwrite with a bad array access.

Here are a couple of good, short tutorials on GDB:

- http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html
- http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/summary.html
- http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html

'Hope that helps!

PS:

When you start debugging, I'd encourage you to set breakpoints in your "Nodes" constructor and your ManipulateArray constructor.

If you don't hit the breakpoint ... then an object never got created ... and you probably found your bug :)

Comment: You can do pretty much everything in eclipse that you can do with the CLI and you get all the nice windows with all your locals, global variables, etc. on one glance and you can use shortcuts in eclipse just as well. Really seems much simpler to me for beginners (eg just double clicking on the interesting line vs. `b class::func`)

Comment: I strongly disagree.  For a lot of different reasons.  Including the fact that getting everything to work in Eclipse can be an awful PITA (especially for a "beginner"), and gcc/gdb/make are usually more likely to "just work".  Visual Studio/C++, on the other hand, is just the opposite - in Microsoft Land, the MSVC IDE is usually the best place to start.  As long as you don't get swept into a lot of auto-code generation... :)  IMHO...

Comment: @Voo: Then she has to learn how to debug in eclipse and later on the advanced gdb commands as well. Why waste time learning a limited language?

Comment: @honk - I completely agree.  There are in fact *many* good reasons for "gdb first".  IMHO...

Comment: @honk Which advanced commands in gdb do you think most people actually use that aren't available in eclipse? And if you just use the vanilla gdb cli, you don't even get windows with your locals, see the current code you're at, etc. Hardly nice for beginners - or anyone else.

Comment: @Voo: Ever tried to debug python code with gdb? Have fun implementing your pretty printer for eclipse, in gdb this is pretty straight-forward. If any frontend I'd point novices to emacs' gud mode.

Comment: @honk Clearly how well you debug **python** code should influence the decision on which debugger you use for **c++** code. Also eclipse does support pretty printing with gdb at least for c++ code. The most important thing at the beginning is seeing all your variables while stepping through the code and seeing the position you're at. All things that the GDB cli doesn't offer out of the box.

Comment: @Voo: Getting further away from debugging in eclipse, but it's interesting that *novice's* tool often much more information than professional tools -- a professional has learned to ask questions to the point to get needed information (like SO), while the novice wades in a wide see of information she isn't sure how to use. WRT your specific comment, `list` is the first gdb command a novice should learn.

Comment: @honk Yep clearly having to type `l` after every step (yes you can automate that, I know) is preferable to just seeing the line marked in color all the time in your actual code :) And seeing all your interesting variables (i.e. the ones used in the current function) without having to type `print <name>` all the time is also just useless information. I know lots of people who use the GDB CLI, but all of them use emacs or something else to get all this information on one glance too (whether you use eclipse, vi or emacs is just a matter of preference, not going to argue on that point)

Answer (score 0):

In a quick look 
void Node::attachNewNode(Node *newNode, int direction) {*newNode = *attachedNode[direction];}
looks to be faulty. The assignment should be attachedNode[direction] = newNode;
You want to attach new node in some direction.

Comment: Yes thank you. This was definitely a big problem. But for some reason Im stilling getting a seg fault.

Comment: your pointer assignment is wrong. So when u say *newNode = *someOtherThing, what you actually mean is newNode = someOtherThing. Assign value to pointer. Will say read about pointers and get feel of it by writing basic examples.